# Finding child element while having parent element

Tags: java, automation, parent-child

There is an element having various children. How can I count the number of its children using parents' xpath?

So far, I have been using this:

```java
List<Webelement> myList = driver.findElements(By.parentXpath)
```

As it is obvious,the size of my list is always 1 cause there is only 1 parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Having parent xpath you can follow the line bellow to get its child:
List myList = driver.findElements(By.parentXpath/child::li/child::div)
instead of just copy and paste the code try to substitute "div" and "lib" with the classes you really have.